# Why do I get "Type could not be found" WCF error on IIS server but not locally with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, web-services, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

The error is:

> The type 'WF.XXX.WebServices.XXXXService', provided as the Service
>   attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the
>   configuration element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found.

Stack Trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: The type 'WF.XXX.WebServices.XXXXService',
>   provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive,
>   or provided in the configuration element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found.]
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String
>   constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +52742
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +1459
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +44
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +623
>
> [ServiceActivationException: The service
>   '/XXXXX/XXXXXService/XXXXService.svc' cannot be activated due to an
>   exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The type
>   'WF.XXX.WebServices.XXXXService', provided as the Service attribute
>   value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration
>   element
>   system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could
>   not be found..]    System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
>   +687598    System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) +190
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +304662
>   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +94

How to fix this error on the server?

***Update on 9/18/2012:***
I have Visual Studio 2012 and .NET Framework 4.5 installed on my machine but server has only .NET Framework 4.0.  I am not sure if this matters, because I built the service with .NET Framework 4.0.

But strangely, I noticed a 4.5 feature when I run my project.  It shows a URL to singleWSDL file, which is not available in .NET 4.0 version.  Why does this show up when the project is built with .NET Framework 4.0?  Here is the screenshot:
[image]

***Update 9/19/12:***

Here is the relavant web.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="XXXXService">
        <!-- Use a bindingNamespace to eliminate tempuri.org -->
        <endpoint address=""  name="XXXXService"
                  binding ="basicHttpBinding" 
                  bindingNamespace="@services.url@/XXXXService" 
                  contract="WF.XXX.WebServices.XXXXService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount="true" />
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: What does the relevant bit of configuration look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions

(1) Make sure you have built your project and the the dll which contains the service type XXXXService is placed in the bin directory.

(2) Single Wsdl is a new 4.5 feature. Since 4.5 is an in-place upgrade of 4.0 you will get the benefit of ?SingleWsdl even if you target your project to 4.0. But when you deploy the same service on a machine with just 4.0 then you will not be able to get this. To get this on your service machine make sure you have 4.5 on that too.

Hope this helps.

Thanks!

Comment: My project had the dlls being built to a folder under the bin directory to match the configuration name, so if the project name was DemoWCF and the configuration was Debug the dll would be here: /bin/Debug/DemoWCF.dll when I removed the Debug/ from the output path and built the dll to here: /bin/DemoWCF.dll everything launched as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the cause was that I had changed the namespace in the code files `IService1.cs` and `Service1.svc.cs` but forgot to change the namespace in the `Service1.svc` file.

E.G. in `service1.svc`

```
< % @ ServiceHost Service="WcfService2.Service1" % >
```

must be changed to:

```
< % @ Service="NewNamespaceName.Service1" % >
```

You can build the solution without Visual Studio catching the typo error.

Comment: I'll just add:
in VS, right click on svc file -> View Markup

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. In my case, simply deleting the bin and obj folders and rebuilding fixed the issue.

Comment: Why the down vote? I'm simple stating what worked for me.